# Enable additional column types

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, office-365, site-settings

I want to add `Image with formatting and constraints for publishing` as an additional column type.

As explained in [Add publishing columns](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Add-publishing-columns-to-content-types-lists-or-libraries-4e268d2e-4822-4bc6-a992-88287119a052), I need to click on "Settings -> Site Settings", then under "Web Designer Galleries", click on "Site Columns".

The problem is, there is no "Web Designer Galleries".

I have everything from this picture, except for the "Web Designer Galleries" (example picture):

[image: Example Site Settings]

Of course, I'm using the admin account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these steps

1. Sign in to Office 365 with your work or school account.
2. Go to the SharePoint admin center.
3. Select Settings.
4. Under Custom Script, check if custom script is disabled.

Source - http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/279959.aspx

Comment: The scripts are disabled. Would enabling them solve my problem?

Comment: Yes. Also read the link I posted. It might take 24 hours to get it activated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is just a little higher up on the page you linked! :-)

> **Note**   Publishing must be enabled by a site collection administrator for these column types to appear. To enable publishing, go to Settings  [image: Small Settings gear that took the place of Site Settings.]> Site Settings. Under Site Collection Administration, click **Site collection features**. Scroll down to SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure and click **Activate**.

Comment: Yes, I had already activated them, but it didn't help.